# Azure CosmoDB with Mongo API for geospatial query error on $geonear not support

Tags: node.js, mongodb-query, azure-cosmosdb

Does anyone try out the geospatial query with MongoAPI on Azure CosmoDB?
I am getting the following error, hope I can get some advices. I am using Node.JS to perform the operation.

> Sending 500 ("Server Error") response:
>    { MongoError: '$geoNear' is not supported
>       at Function.MongoError.create (D:\DinDins\admin-site\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\error.js:31:11)

Answer (score 0):

Understood from Azure CosmosDB support, mongo command $geonear in the aggregate pipeline is currently not supported. Will need to use $near to replace the function.